# String to NSNumber in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, ios8, nsnumber

I found a method to convert String to NSNumber, but the code is in Objective-C. I have tried converting it to Swift but it is not working.

The code I am using:

```
NSNumberFormatter *f = [[NSNumberFormatter alloc] init];
f.numberStyle = NSNumberFormatterDecimalStyle;
NSNumber *myNumber = [f numberFromString:@"42222222222"];
```

and in Swift I am using it in this way:

```
var i = NSNumberFormatter.numberFromString("42")
```

But this code is not working. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: try this    NSNumberFormatter().numberFromString("42")!.doubleValue

Answer (score 162, accepted):

### Swift 3.0

`NSNumber(integer:myInteger)` has changed to `NSNumber(value:myInteger)`

```
let someString = "42222222222"
if let myInteger = Int(someString) {
    let myNumber = NSNumber(value:myInteger)
}
```

---

### Swift 2.0

Use the `Int()` initialiser like this.

```
let someString = "42222222222"
if let myInteger = Int(someString) {
    let myNumber = NSNumber(integer:myInteger)
    print(myNumber)
} else {
    print("'\(someString)' did not convert to an Int")
}
```

This can be done in one line if you already know the string will convert perfectly or you just don't care.

```
let myNumber = Int("42222222222")!
```

---

### Swift 1.0

Use the `toInt()` method.

```
let someString = "42222222222"
if let myInteger = someString.toInt() {
    let myNumber = NSNumber(integer:myInteger)
    println(myNumber)
} else {
    println("'\(someString)' did not convert to an Int")
}
```

Comment: my number is long long not interger and replacing interger to longlong shows error?

Comment: are you saying that your string is not in this format: "42" ?

Comment: Perhaps you could update your question with a string in the format you want?

Comment: Swap 2.0 and 1.0 answers, placing 2.0 on top.

Comment: @SwiftArchitect feel free to edit my answer if you feel it could be structured better.

Comment: If I do it will probably be declined as "no improvement" (-:

Comment: You should be really careful with using Int and Int64 - if the number can be bigger than Int32 and your app can run on iPhone 5 or older, use Int64 and not Int

Comment: They couldn't bang our asses any other way, so they made swift... Putting us in a position to ask such simple questions.

Comment: Keep in mind, the string may contain double value, not int. In this case you should use if let myInteger = Double(someString)

Answer (score 16):

Or do it just in one line:

```
NSNumberFormatter().numberFromString("55")!.decimalValue
```

Comment: Like David Berry commented below, be careful with creating NSNumberFormatters like this as they are expensive to create. Better caching or using a singleton if using the same formatter more than once.

Comment: Has been updated for Swift 5:
```NumberFormatter().number(from: "55")!```

Answer (score 9):

In latest Swift:

```
let number = NumberFormatter().number(from: "1234")
```

Answer (score 8):

**Swift 2**

Try this:

```
var num = NSNumber(int: Int32("22")!)
```

**Swift 3.x**

```
 NSNumber(value: Int32("22")!)
```

Comment: with Swift 3.x this is now.. `NSNumber.init( value: Int32("22")!)`

Comment: no need to initialize with '.init'. simply write: NSNumber(value: Int32("22")!)

Answer (score 6):

You can use the following code if you must use `NSNumberFormatter`. 
It's simpler to use Wezly's method.

```
let formatter = NSNumberFormatter()
formatter.numberStyle = NSNumberFormatterStyle.DecimalStyle;
if let number = formatter.numberFromString("42") {
    println(number)
}
```

Comment: Note also that `NSNumberFormatter` is expensive to create, and should be cached whenever possible instead of being created every time it's used.

Answer (score 3):

Swift 5

```
let myInt = NumberFormatter().number(from: "42")
```

Answer (score 2):

I do use extension in swift 3/4 and it's cool.

```
extension String {
    var numberValue: NSNumber? {
        if let value = Int(self) {
            return NSNumber(value: value)
        }
        return nil
    }
}
```

and then just use following code:

```
stringVariable.numberValue
```

What is cool is that you don't need a chain of `if` statements to unwrap the optional values.
For instance,

```
if let _ = stringVariable, let intValue = Int(stringVariable!) {
    doSomething(NSNumber.init(value: intValue))
}
```

can be replaced by:

```
doSomething(stringVariable?.numberValue)
```

Answer (score -1):

("23" as NSString).integerValue 
("23.5" as NSString).doubleValue

and so on .

Answer (score -5):

> Try Once

```
let myString = "123"
let myInt = NSNumber(value: Int(myString) ?? 0)
```